# SBT project with different versions of dependency for plugin and itself?

Tags: sbt

I have a problem in a SBT project where there are two different versions of Apache HttpClient **4.1.3** and **4.3.1**.

I made a small sbt project to reproduce the issue - https://github.com/eirslett/sbt-httpclient-problem

Does anybody know how this can be resolved? How can I have a sbt plugin that uses version 4.3.1, and still do HTTP requests from my build?

Comment: It worked fine for me. `httpclient-4.3.1.jar` was used.

Comment: Strange - Travis CI also runs it just fine:
https://travis-ci.org/eirslett/sbt-httpclient-problem/builds/20325787

But I'm on a Windows 7 box (64 bit) java 1.7.0_01, there might be an OS-spesific problem?

Comment: (I just updated to java 1.7.0_51 just to rule out that as a problem.)

Comment: I'm on MacOS X with the latest version of Java 1.7.0_51. There really could be OS-specific.

Comment: possibly the ordering of claspaths in different platforms is what you're seeing.  The reality these kinds of issues mean you need to isolate classpaths for the competing versions.  If I can get an example of how for you, I will.

The trick is you resolve the apache you want in a hidden config, and then load it via reflection in a separate classloader....